# Create pdf with tooltips in python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, tooltip

This a python copy of the popular and highly upvoted [Create pdf with tooltips in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691780/create-pdf-with-tooltips-in-r) .

Simple question: Is there a way to plot a graph from python in a pdf file and include tooltips?

Comment: You could try modeling your data with directed graph tuples such as

Comment: You could try modeling your data with directed graph tuples such as [(a,b), (a1,b1), and so on...] then put that into a graphviz graph.  Then write all that into a pdf with something like pypdf.   Graphviz can generate images such as jpg, gif, etc (its limited to what your system can do, but that is discoverable at run time).  Then when you create the pdf, one inserts the image into the pdf file. -- Thats the heart of the solution ... so yes its doable.

Comment: @David I am not sure this helps. How do you add tooltips this way? See the linked R question for examples of what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the matplotlib pgf backend to do that. Then you can use different packages at the preamble. In this case I am using the pdfcomment.

This is a very simple example, but I think you can go from here!

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
pgf_with_pdflatex = {
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage[author={me}]{pdfcomment}",
    ]
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_pdflatex)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))

for i in range(5):
    plt.text(i,i,r"\pdftooltip{o}{(%d,%d)}"%(i,i))

plt.savefig("tooltips.pdf")
```

There is a slight misplacement of the character "o", but that can be fixed with few tweaks.
It is also much simpler than the R case.

PS: The tooltips can only be visualised with Acrobat Reader.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It looks like there is a way to add tooltips in LaTeX that should work with evince at least. Do you think matplotlib can do this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers

Comment: I believe it would work. I will have a look on that later and will post something here if succeed. Cheers

Comment: This works well, except when I run it I get an extra blank page. I've posted the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447490/matplotlib-pgf-pdfcomment-preamble-causing-blank-extra-page 
and I'll comment again if anyone can find a solution.