# matplotlib pgf pdfcomment preamble causing blank extra page

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, tooltip, pdflatex

I am trying to add some tooltips to a matplotlib pdf file. To do this I am using pgf so I can add "pdfcomment" in the preamble. However, when I add pdfcomment to the preamble I get a blank extra page. This does not happen with other packages like xcolor and hyperref (for example).

Here is the code as I'm using it for testing, which I got from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245470/6442007):

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.use("pgf")
pgf_with_pdflatex = {
  "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
  "pgf.preamble": r"\usepackage{pdfcomment}",
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_pdflatex)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
for i in range(5):
    plt.text(i,i,r"\pdftooltip{\rule{0.3cm}{0.3cm}}{(%d,%d)}" % (i,i))
    
plt.plot(range(5), linewidth = 10)
plt.savefig("tooltips.pdf")
plt.close()
```

Which works, except that it makes an extra page. Below is a minimalist version which reproduces the problem.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams["pgf.texsystem"] = "pdflatex"
#mpl.rcParams["pgf.preamble"] = r"\usepackage{pdfcomment}" # uncomment to get blank page
plt.plot(range(5), linewidth = 10)
plt.savefig("tooltips.pdf")
plt.close()
```

Essentially if you uncomment that one line you will get an extra blank page as output which I don't want. Below are two example screenshots that I get, one with the extra page and one without (all I changed was uncommenting the line).

[image: with line commented]

[image: with line uncommented]

As extra information, my pdflatex version is:

> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

python3 version is:

> Python 3.8.10

Matplotlib version is:

> 3.3.2

Please help and please be kind, this is my first time posting a question.

Edit: as requested [here is the intermediate LaTeX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y91VGUy-rSliu4buFB3uo2Dx2MsEo-s3/view?usp=sharing). This is in the form of a pgf file which one would include in a tex document I think. I wasn't sure how to get the .tex directly.

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: I think I have added the appropriate file, I wasn't sure how to get a .tex file. The link is at the bottom with "Edit"

Comment: It would be interesting to see the .tex file. With a simple `\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
 \input{tooltips_uncommented.pgf}
\end{document}` I get only one page

Comment: I tried just putting what you wrote in a .tex file and it compiled to one page. Then I tried adding the extra packages you list to the pgf.preamble in the matplotlib version and it still gives two pages. So I'm really not sure what the issue is since it works on LaTeX alone, just not in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but I think I found a work around. Here is the modified minimal version which only outputs a single page. Based on the comment by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the problem is with matplotlib not LaTeX, so I just include a pdflatex call in the script. Here is the minimal working version:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams["pgf.texsystem"] = "pdflatex"
mpl.rcParams["pgf.preamble"] = r"\usepackage{pdfcomment}"
plt.plot(range(5), linewidth = 10, zorder = 10)
plt.savefig("tooltips.pgf")
plt.close()
import subprocess
with open("tooltips.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write(r"""
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\input{tooltips.pgf}
\end{document}
    """)
subprocess.run(["pdflatex", "tooltips.tex"])
```

Note that matplotlib outputs a .pgf file instead of a .pdf file.